# How to make striking glaze drizzle?

Tags: icing, coloring, glaze

In this video the chefs drizzle two colours across their cakes:

https://youtu.be/EJsUDT9Z_Io?t=11m42s

In the comments the presenting chef explains that she doesn't know what that drizzle is but that it could be food colouring and condensed milk.

Having tried this and found it ineffective, I have to ask how else could this very striking colour be made without it fading or melting into the rest of the glaze?

Comment: Be skeptical of any chef who doesn't know which ingredients he or she is using.

Comment: Food colouring pastes are much stronger than the typical liquids, so any recipe that doesn't add a fair bit of water is better coloured with paste

Comment: @moscafj The 'presenting' chef is the commentator in this case, not the chef making the dish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s cocoa butter and colour. Probably powdered colour for best results.